# How can I combine two of them and create a new serializer with new fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am facing one issue with formating the response of DRF

I am sharing my model Details here

```
class Plan(AuditFields, Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    object_id = models.UUIDField(
        unique=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Public identifier')
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    team = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_team")


class PlanDetail(AuditFields, Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(
        Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    plan_stage = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status_of_plan = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Using the Above models I need to create a  response like this . But I am facing some issues with this

```
       plan details :  [
   {
            "plan_stage": "Sample1",
            "status_of_plan": "Completed",
            "start_date": "2019-07-01",
            "end_date": "2019-07-01",
        },
        {
            "plan_stage": "Sample2",
            "status_of_plan": "Not Commenced",
            "start_date": "2019-08-01",
            "end_date": "2019-08-31",
        },
        {
            "plan_stage": "Sample3",
            "status_of_plan": "Not Commenced",
            "start_date": "2019-09-01",
            "end_date": "2019-09-30",
        },
        {
            "plan_stage": "Sample4",
            "status_of_plan": "Not Commenced",
            "start_date": "2019-10-01",
            "end_date": "2019-10-31",
        },
        {
            "plan_stage": "Sample 5",
            "status_of_plan": "Completed",
            "start_date": "2019-11-01",
            "end_date": "2019-11-30",
        },
        {
            "plan_stage": "End Date (Final Report)",
            "status_of_plan": "Completed",
            "start_date": "2019-12-01",
            "end_date": "2019-12-31",
        }


    ]
plan :{
"id" : 1.
"object_id": 456789023456546,
"plan_name" : "Sample",
"team":['Sachin','Dravid']

}
```

I am using two serializers and trying it ..... But its not works in this case

```
class PlanningSerializer(ModelSerializer):
 '''THis is for Model Plan '''
    team = TeamSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Plan
    exclude = ['deleted_at']

class PlanningDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
plan = PlanningSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PlanDetail
        exclude = ['deleted_at']
```

But I am facing one issue

I am getting response like this

```
[
    {
        "plan_stage": "Sample1",
        "status_of_plan": "Completed",
        "start_date": "2019-07-01",
        "end_date": "2019-07-01",
        "plan": {
                   "id" : 1.
                 "object_id": 456789023456546,
                 "plan_name" : "Sample",
                "team":['Sachin','Dravid']    
              }
    },
    {
        "plan_stage": "Sample2",
        "status_of_plan": "Not Commenced",
        "start_date": "2019-08-01",
        "end_date": "2019-08-31",
        "plan": {
                   "id" : 1.
                 "object_id": 456789023456546,
                 "plan_name" : "Sample",
                "team":['Sachin','Dravid']    
              }
    },
    {
        "plan_stage": "Sample3",
        "status_of_plan": "Not Commenced",
        "start_date": "2019-09-01",
        "end_date": "2019-09-30",
        "plan": {
                   "id" : 1.
                 "object_id": 456789023456546,
                 "plan_name" : "Sample",
                "team":['Sachin','Dravid']    
              }
    },
    {
        "plan_stage": "Sample4",
        "status_of_plan": "Not Commenced",
        "start_date": "2019-10-01",
        "end_date": "2019-10-31",
        "plan": {
                   "id" : 1.
                 "object_id": 456789023456546,
                 "plan_name" : "Sample",
                "team":['Sachin','Dravid']    
              }
    },
    {
        "plan_stage": "Sample 5",
        "status_of_plan": "Completed",
        "start_date": "2019-11-01",
        "end_date": "2019-11-30",
        "plan": {
                   "id" : 1.
                 "object_id": 456789023456546,
                 "plan_name" : "Sample",
                "team":['Sachin','Dravid']    
              }
    },
    {
        "plan_stage": "Sample6",
        "status_of_plan": "Completed",
        "start_date": "2019-12-01",
        "end_date": "2019-12-31",
        "plan": {
                   "id" : 1.
                 "object_id": 456789023456546,
                 "plan_name" : "Sample",
                "team":['Sachin','Dravid']    
              }
    }
]
```

How can I combine two of them and create a new serializer with new fields

Answer (score 3):

add plan field to your PlanningDetailsSerializer exclude fields.

```
class PlanningDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = PlanDetail
      exclude = ['deleted_at', 'plan']
```

If you want to see results in the same response, as a suggesstion try this:

```
class PlanningAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       plan_details = PlanDetail.objects.all() # or some query
       plan = Plan.objects.all()  # or some query
       plan_detail_serializer = PlanDetail(data=plan_details, many=True)
       plan_serializer = Plan(data=plan, many=True)
       return Response({"plan_details": plan_detail_serializer.data, "plan": plan_serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: But How can I get the Plan alone on the same Serializer

Comment: I need response like this 

 plan details :  [ plan details : {
...............
}
Plan: {...................}
]

Comment: Updated my answer for your last comment.

Comment: Please Explain this two statments

      plan_detail_serializer = PlanDetail(data=plan_details)
       plan_serializer = Plan(data=plan)

Comment: You want two different format data so i use two serializer. These serializers, serialize data from database.